# React create stack navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react native and expo. I am getting error message after run expo and it says:

```
Error: Creating a navigator doesn't take an argument. Maybe you are trying to use React Navigation 4 API with React Navigation 5? See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x for migration guide.
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from './components/Home.js'
import Movie from './components/Movie.js'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppNavigator />
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  'Home': Home,
  'Movie': Movie,
})
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.9",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Could you please help to resolve this issue?
I am waiting for your response.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the navigator in the old way, the code for V5 which you are using should be like below.

You will have to import NavigationContainer as well.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Movie" component={Movie} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

More reference can be found here
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/